# Xcode - Uploading things to servers / web services (Just How?!)

Tags: objective-c, ios, database, xcode

Get ready because this may be a prett nooby question.

Lets look at an app like twitter. You can post a tweet and others can view if from their phone. How ? It uploads and retrieves to and from a database.

Say I wanted to create an app like twitter where you can share pictures and it shows up in someone's feed... How would that work?

In xcode, how can I create an app that uploads an app to a database and another user can press a Button to retrieve it. Is there a database API or service?

I'm just kind of stuck on this, I'm not sure what the correct way is. How can I upload data to a database so another user can see it in their app?

I'm not asking for code, just links, simple steps, APIs? I just don't know how it works and can't really find resources because I don't know the right terminology...

Would uploading to core data then syncing Core data with a database (again what database can I use?) be easy and the best way to do it?

Update:

Ok, so you have given me some great answers. php files on web services / servers, could you point me towards a book (on amazon) or something that can guide me through this whole process. I want to start up and work my way through this, I am not sure which is the best way, all these possibilities overwhelm me!

So any big resources that can really help me understand? I dont mind even starting with just uploading a string to a web service backend and retrieving it!

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried the Core Data approach, and keep in mind what I'm doing may not be the best way. (I just started with this too) The basic idea is that you'll have to create different PHP files on your server to handle the SQL operations. From there you can make requests for them from within the app by passing hashed data through isset's in the URL.

Comment: Mostly this kind of service employs a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) protocol.  You can do some sort of remote SQL, but it's much poorer performance and harder to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to make your own server, then take a look at [Parse](http://parse.com), they give you API to work with their cloud database, it should be a good starting point and very well documented.

If you do want to make server side yourself, then it's a much broader question. A popular way to do it is to have a web app, say written in Rails, with REST API that you can talk to from the app. See this [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ios-photo-sharing-geo-location-service) about creating photo sharing app on heroku, it will get you started, and overall it's a good overview of how things like these work.

Comment: Which do you think would be better, creating your own server or using a server? Also, could you give me a smaller tutorial perhaps on just transferring a string to a server and then retrieving it on anotehr device?

Comment: Sorry I just feel very overwhelmed because it looks like there are many different ways of doing things. I want to take it slow, start off by just uploading a string, I want to know the best way... if I create an app for sharing photos (for example) which is better creating your own server or using parse.... or which is more commonly used and better

Just really stuck about this whole thing I do not know php

Comment: Is there a book that explains everything about this?

Comment: Do you think MySQL is the best?

Comment: Theres is no "best" here, you will have to decide for yourself at some point. Thus start with anything you feel more interesting or familiar. As of which way to take first, if you are not familiar with web programming at all I would start with Parse, that will get you closer to working iOS app faster.

Answer (score 2):

Hi try this tutorial it is simple and just what you need to get an idea how thing works .

How To Create an App Like Instagram With a Web Service Backend – Part 1/2

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13511/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-12

There are a lot more tutorial on that website . Have fun.

Comment: I'd prefer not to dig to deep into something I have almost no knowledge on. Could you point me to any resources that start of with something really simple possibly just some text or a full book that can guide me

Comment: there is not a simple way to do this , you need to access the webserver - set your API - write your code (xcode) - send data to webserver - . That tutorial in my link is very simple to follow and easy , step by step. if you can not follow it , you may need to try and make a simple app to begin with.

Comment: Thats what I am asking. Is tehre a simpler version, like uploading text to a web server and retireve it

Comment: any app that needs to send data  to a webserver you need to write your API's to GET and POST data . unless you use something like Parse or other web services. your best resource is http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Comment: Thanks, I am going to go ahead and use the Amazon S3 Service, do you know about it?

Comment: Not really but just read the Documentation from Amazon and good luck .